# JavaScript: поиск одинаковой подстроки в массиве строк

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки, подстрока

Существует переменная, в которой хранится массив строк. Нужно найти подстроку, которая бы была честью каждой строки массива с позиции 0 (с самого начала). Например для такого массива строк:
`['qwert4', 'qwert7y', 'qwers4', 'qw4qwer']` ответом должна была бы быть строка `qw`. Пробовал с помощью метода перебора массива `reduce`, но я не совсем понимаю логику самого алгоритма поиска совпадающей части. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
arr = ['qwerttt', 'qwerft43t', 'qwers4', 'qwer.qwer', 'qwerAtAyu'];
var resReduce = arr.reduce(function(x, y) {
    var z = [];
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i] == y[i]) {
            z[i] = x[i];
        } else break;
    }
    x = z.join("");
    return x;
});
console.log(resReduce);
```

Как просили с помощью reduce(). Классная задачка!

Comment: Алексей, спасибо за отличное решение.

Comment: @MaksMihalchuk, какой ответ должен быть для массива: `['qwerttt', 'qwerft43t']`?

Comment: if (x[i] == y[i]) {
             z[i] = x[i];
         } else break;   С благодарностью за подсказку! И ещё, раз такая пьянка, подскажите материалы по прокачке своих знаний в js?

Answer (score 1):

1. Берете первую букву первой строки и фильтруете весь массив, оставляя только те строки, которые начинаются с первой буквы.
2. Если массив стал меньше, чем был такой подстроки нет. Иначе берете первые 2 буквы первой строки и опять фильтруете массив.
3. Повторяете шаг 2 до тех пор, пока либо массив не станет меньше чем был, либо размер подстроки не станет больше самого маленького элемента в массиве.

Если сложно сразу через `reduce` и `filter` писать - сделайте итеративно.

Comment: фильтровать не нужно, достаточно просто проверять наличие элемента

Answer (score 1):

Я не уверен что reduce совсем то, reduce это перебор массива с имеющимся первым параметром, у которого задается значение изначально, после каждого раза когда происходит return, значение меняется на получившееся, а второй параметр это значение из массива

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

var result = arr.reduce(function(sum, current) { // sum меняется каждый раз после прохода
  return sum + current;
}, 0); // 0 - изначальный параметр который задается
```

А вот вариант ответа, который я могу предложить, павда для больших значений он долгий

```
var arr = ['qwert4', 'qwert7y', 'qwers4', 'qw4qwer'], 
    ind = -1;

for(var i =0; i < arr.length - 2; i++) {

  while(true) {

    if( arr[i][ind] == arr[i+1][ind] && ind == -1 ) 
      ind++;
    else if( arr[i][ind] == arr[i+1][ind] ) 
      ind++;
    else 
      ind--;
      break;
  }
}
```

Ответ 1 то есть первый две буквы, как вариант, я не тестил, если найдутся ошибки, обращайся, посмотрю

Answer (score 1):

Самая простая реализация "в лоб" через итерации.

```
function isMatchCharThroughWords(index, words) {
  let firstWord = words[0];
  let char = firstWord[index];
  for (let i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
    let word = words[i];
    if (word[index] !== char) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function findCommonMatch(words) {
  let result = '';
  let firstWord = words[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < firstWord.length; i++) {
    if (isMatchCharThroughWords(i, words)) {
      result += firstWord[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

let res = findCommonMatch(['qwert4', 'qwert7y', 'qwers4', 'qw4qwer']);
console.log(res); // qw
```